# Android - ZXing Scanner error in stopCamera inside onPause

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, zxing

I have an application that needs ZXing Scanner, the scanner is working but there is an error. I have a button that opens the ScannerView

```
 mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(MainActivity.this);
 setContentView(mScannerView);
 mScannerView.setResultHandler(MainActivity.this);
 mScannerView.startCamera();
```

Here's what handles the result

```
@Override
public void handleResult(final Result rawResult) {

    Log.e("handler", rawResult.getText());
    Log.e("handler", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    final String result = rawResult.getText();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage(result);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BalanceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("result", result);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

BalanceActivity opens a BlueTooth Connection.

This is my onPause

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera(); //this is where the error points in
}
```

Here is my error log

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.busticketing.busticketing, PID: 16103
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.busticketing.busticketing/com.busticketing.busticketing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3659)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3618)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:172)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference
 at com.busticketing.busticketing.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:160)
 at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6373)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1308)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3618) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:172) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The Application is working fine, but every time I tap the button that opens ZXing, this error occur "Unfortunately, ApplicationName has stopped." But continues to the next Activity and works well. I want to know what makes this error occur. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you use on start() method?

Comment: no onStart(), i just used onCreate() and onPause()

Comment: OPen Camera OnStart() may be thats the problem

Comment: maintain whole activity lifecycle

Comment: I put the stopCamera() inside the onClick event in the handleResult class. It worked perfectly now =)

Comment: ok thats great cheers!